# extracting segment from string with multiple identical symbols

Tags: r

I’m trying to extract “A35-9B004” out of “A35-9B004-65g3h” using the function sub in R but keep failing. I’ve tried using regular expressions but can´t seem to figure out how to handle the double “-“ in the string, and can only extract first or last segment in the string.

Thank you!

```
x<-"A35-9B004-65g3h"
sub(".*-", "",x)
[1] "65g3h"
sub("*-.*", "", x)
[1] "A35"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use the pattern to match the `-` followed by one or more characters that are not a `-` (`[^-]+`) till the end (`$)` of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("-[^-]+$", "", x)
[1] "A35-9B004"
```

---

Or use `trimws` with `whitespace` that takes a regex

```
trimws(x, whitespace = "-[^-]+")
[1] "A35-9B004"
```